# Select last order date, all the order id and user id for particular seller in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to postgreSQL

Updated Initial Question:

I have two tables `orders` & `users`

| user_id | username |
| --- | --- |
| a | user1 |
| b | user2 |
| c | user3 |

| order_id | ordered_at | user_id | seller_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-10 | a | s1 |
| 2 | 2022-08-09 | b | s1 |
| 3 | 2022-07-06 | a | s2 |
| 4 | 2022-08-01 | a | s1 |
| 5 | 2022-05-02 | c | s1 |
| 6 | 2022-08-11 | b | s2 |
| 7 | 2022-08-12 | b | s1 |

My postgres SQL query should give me the result for seller s1:

| order_id | last_purchase | user_id | username |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-10 | a | user1 |
| 4 | 2022-08-10 | a | user1 |
| 2 | 2022-08-12 | b | user2 |
| 7 | 2022-08-12 | b | user2 |
| 5 | 2022-05-02 | c | user3 |

For this I have wrote the SQL query:

```
        SELECT
            MAX(orders.ordered_at) AS last_purchase,
            orders.order_id AS order_id,
            users.user_id AS users_id,
            users.username as username
        FROM
            orders
        INNER JOIN
            users
        ON
            orders.user_id = users.user_id
        WHERE 
            orders.seller_id='s1'
        GROUP BY users.user_id;
```

I am not getting the desired output

Any suggestions or help is welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: You need to add all table fields that are not in aggregate functions in the group by clause.  This is SQL Ansi standard. Mysql allowed this and causes confusion to a lot of people. So for your query to work `group by orders.order_id, users.users_id, users.username`

Comment: @JorgeCampos this doesn't give me desired result. Have I tried doing the above told by you before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I am understanding your question you want last purchase to be the max date per user id.  if so use a windowing function

```
 SELECT
            MAX(orders.ordered_at) over
             (partition by users.users_id  order by orders.ordered_at desc) as 
             last_purchase,
            orders.order_id AS order_id,
            users.users_id AS users_id,
            users.username as username
        FROM
            orders
        INNER JOIN
            users
        ON
            orders.user_id = users.id
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer. It is correct. :)  Can I please know, if I extend the orders table to fetch last_purchase and other fields only for a particular seller_id then what changes I have to make in the above query ?

Comment: I have update my above question fully regarding the above comment for your clarity. @Bryan Dellinger

Comment: don't think the windowing function will change as long as you still want  max ordered_at per user_id